# How to get tkinter program to stay behind all windows programs and apps

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, attributes

I am trying to make a python script that creates a Windows
98 look alike that allows the user to run Windows 10 but making it appear to be Windows
98. (a fun project that is obviously no something I will not sell because of copyright issues)
I have managed to make the window fullscreen without the title bar and I have managed to get even the a start menu and desktop icons that turn blue when you select them as the old Windows
98 era pcs did.

The user can double click a desktop icon and it will open the Windows 10 equivalent. For example, my documents sends a command to the terminal that asks file explorer to open to user documents. Internet Explorer opens whatever your default internet browser is and these windows successfully open on top of the fake Windows
98 program. However, the struggle I'm having is that once the user clicks into the desktop area of the fake Windows
98 program Tkinter treats it like a program that is on it's own (which it is) and then hides the Windows 10 program behind the fake Windows
98 screen.

I was able to achieve this effect in linux os's by using the window attribute splash or desktop like so

```
window.attributes('-type', 'splash')
```

or...

```
window.attributes('-type', 'desktop')
```

For linux this second parameter works best and properly keeps stays at the bottom of the pile of programs at all times as if it was an interactive desktop image.

I have not found any attributes like the desktop attribute that work with Windows 10
the one I am currently using is

```
window.wm_attributes("-fullscreen", -1)
```

because windows computers throw an error whenever they run the script with the
attribute that works.

I am also trying to figure out how to get the python script to monitor which Windows 10 programs are running so that it can display it in as a tile in the taskbar as most os's are able to do. so that one can select it and open the program without alt tabbing all the time.

In summery I am asking 2 questions

1. How do I get the tkinter program to stay at the bottom of the window pile and also behind the Windows 10 taskbar but in front of the Windows 10 desktop icons
2. How do I get python to monitor what programs are open and retrieve the title bar text a well as the icon image in order to make taskbar tiles appear in the custom Windows
   98 taskbar I'm making?

Any help would be appreciated

I do not know object oriented programming yet. I can send the code here if someone wants to see it however it's very very long and I don't want to be spammy.

Thanks! Billie